# Turtle GUI improvement

Tags: python, user-interface, turtle-graphics

I'm a 11th grader (5th year student) that just started studying Python programming. I am trying to make a GUI where I can chose what shape I want to draw with turtle and input the values needed to draw out the shape. I managed to do that with the following code (where I already did the functions of the turtle fractals and imported that file):

```
from tkinter import *

import turtlegraphics

from turtle import *

import math


#set up the window

root = Tk()

root.title('Turtle shapes')

root.geometry('300x200+100+100')



#make the interface

turtleLabel = Label(root, text = 'Turtle Fractals Generator')

turtleLabel.grid(row = 0, column =1, columnspan =2)



#order widgets

orderLabel = Label(root, text ='Order')

orderLabel.grid(row = 1, column =0)



orderStr = StringVar()

orderEntry = Entry(root, textvariable = orderStr)

orderEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 2)



#length widgets

lengthLabel = Label(root, text ='Length')

lengthLabel.grid(row = 2, column =0)



lengthStr = StringVar()

lengthEntry = Entry(root, textvariable = lengthStr)

lengthEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 1, columnspan = 2)



#button widgets

def clearF():

    #Clear the entries

    orderStr.set('')

    lengthStr.set('')







    return

#end def

clearButton = Button(root, text ='Clear', command = clearF)

clearButton.grid(row = 3, column =1)





def treeF():

    order = int(orderStr.get())

    length = float(lengthStr.get())





    turtlegraphics.tree(order,length, pen)







    return

#end def

treeButton = Button(root, text ='Tree', command = treeF)

treeButton.grid(row = 1, column =3)


#make a gasket button

def gasketF():

    order = int(orderStr.get())

    length = float(lengthStr.get())

    turtlegraphics.gasket(order,length,pen)

    return
#end def

gasButton = Button(root, text ='Gasket', command = gasketF)

gasButton.grid(row = 2, column =3)


#make a dandelion button
def dandelionF():

    order = int(orderStr.get())

    length = float(lengthStr.get())

    turtlegraphics.tree4(order,length,pen)

    return
#end def

danButton = Button(root, text ='Dandelion', command = dandelionF)

danButton.grid(row = 3, column =3)


#make flalke button
def kevinF():

    order = int(orderStr.get())

    length = float(lengthStr.get())

    turtlegraphics.k(order,length,pen)



    return
#end def
def flakeF():
    order = int(orderStr.get())

    length = float(lengthStr.get())

    turtlegraphics.flake(order,length,pen)

    return
#end def






flakeButton = Button(root, text ='Flake', command = flakeF)

flakeButton.grid(row = 4, column =3)




#make a screen and a pen

pen = Pen()

screen = Screen()



pen.speed(0)

pen.color('blue')

pen.width(3)



screen.bgcolor('white')



root.mainloop()
```

However, I want to try and put a list to chose the shape from rather than having several buttons. I don't understand much about lists due to the fact that I wasn't taught it yet but after doing research this is what I got:

```
'''

program gui to draw turtle fractals

'''



from tkinter import *

import turtlegraphics

from turtle import *

import math


#make a screen and a pen

pen = Pen()


def treeF():

    order = int(orderStr.get())

    length = float(lengthStr.get())


    turtlegraphics.tree(order,length, pen)


    return

#end def

#make a gasket button

def gasketF():

   order = int(orderStr.get())

   length = float(lengthStr.get())

   turtlegraphics.gasket(order,length,pen)

   return
#end def


#make a dandelion button
def dandelionF():

    order = int(orderStr.get())

    length = float(lengthStr.get())

    turtlegraphics.tree4(order,length,pen)

    return
#end def


#make flalke button
def kevinF():

    order = int(orderStr.get())

    length = float(lengthStr.get())

    turtlegraphics.k(order,length,pen)



    return
#end def
def flakeF():
    order = int(orderStr.get())

    length = float(lengthStr.get())

    turtlegraphics.flake(order,length,pen)

    return
#end def
screen = Screen()


pen.speed(0)

pen.color('blue')

pen.width(3)



screen.bgcolor('white')

#set up the window

root = Tk()

root.title('turtle shapes')

root.geometry('600x300+100+100')


#make the interface

turtleLabel = Label(root, text = 'Turtle Fractals Generator')

turtleLabel.grid(row = 0, column =1, columnspan =2)



#order widgets

orderLabel = Label(root, text ='Order')

orderLabel.grid(row = 1, column =0)



orderStr = StringVar()

orderEntry = Entry(root, textvariable = orderStr)

orderEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 2)



#length widgets

lengthLabel = Label(root, text ='Length')

lengthLabel.grid(row = 2, column =0)



lengthStr = StringVar()

lengthEntry = Entry(root, textvariable = lengthStr)

lengthEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 1, columnspan = 2)



#button widgets

def clearF():

    #Clear the entries

    orderStr.set('')

    lengthStr.set('')

    return

#end def

clearButton = Button(root, text ='Clear', command = clearF)

clearButton.grid(row = 3, column =1)

#list

def selection():
    obj = nameList.curselection()[0]
    if obj == 'tree':
          command = treeF
          return
    if obj == 'dandelion':
          command = dandelionF
          return
    if obj == 'flake':
          command = flakeF
          return
    if obj == 'gasketF':
          command = gasketF
          return


    #end if


  #end def

#create list
listbox = Listbox(root,selectmode = SINGLE) #select mode is type of 
selection
listButton= Button(root, text = 'chose fractal') 

labelVar = StringVar()
nameLabel = Label(root, textvariable = labelVar)
nameLabel.grid(row = 2 , column = 7, columnspan = 2)
labelVar.set('choose a fractal') 


names = ['tree','dandelion','flake','gasket']
nameList = Listbox(root)
for i in names:
     nameList.insert(END, i)
nameList.grid(row = 4, column =7, columnspan = 2)

selectionButton = Button(root, text = 'draw', command = selection)
selectionButton.grid(row = 5, column = 7, columnspan = 2)



root.mainloop()
```

I know something is wrong with my code, but I can't tell what I did wrong. When I run my code I get no error whatsoever, but it does not draw the shape. In addition, the clear button does not do its function when clicked. How can I can I fix this?

Comment: don't put empty line after every line with code - it makes code too long to read it. [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: what is `turtlegraphics` ? I can't run it without `turtlegraphics`

Comment: BTW: instead of `StringVar` you can use `IntVar` (it gives integer value) and `DoubleVar` (it gives float value)

Comment: inside `selection()` you create local variable `command=`. It is not `command=` in button. If you want to execute function then do it instead of assigning to variable - ie. `if obj == 'tree': treeF()`

Comment: `nameList.curselection()[0]` returns index of selected element (use `print(nameList.curselection()[0])` to see this) so you need `if obj == 0: treeF()` or you have to get text from `names` - `obj = names[nameList.curselection()[0]]`

Comment: if you have problem then use `print()` and `print(type(...))` to display values and types of variables - it helps to find mistake. You can also print text which inform which part of code is executed and results from `if/elif` - ie. `print(obj, obj == "tree")`

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem is how `selection()` works -- it was comparing numbers to strings and have the code necessary to execute any of the subprograms.  I've reworked it below to get the behavior you desire.  I've also made other changes and simplifications:

```
from tkinter import *

from turtle import Pen, Screen

import turtlegraphics

def treeF():

    order = int(orderEntry.get())
    length = float(lengthEntry.get())

    turtlegraphics.tree(order, length, pen)

def dandelionF():

    order = int(orderEntry.get())
    length = float(lengthEntry.get())

    turtlegraphics.tree4(order, length, pen)

def flakeF():

    order = int(orderEntry.get())
    length = float(lengthEntry.get())

    turtlegraphics.flake(order, length, pen)

def gasketF():

    order = int(orderEntry.get())
    length = float(lengthEntry.get())

    turtlegraphics.gasket(order, length, pen)

def kevinF():

    order = int(orderEntry.get())
    length = float(lengthEntry.get())

    turtlegraphics.k(order, length, pen)

fractals = [('tree', treeF), ('dandelion', dandelionF), ('flake', flakeF), ('gasket', gasketF), ('kevin', kevinF)]

# make a screen and a pen

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('white')

pen = Pen()
pen.speed('fastest')
pen.color('blue')
pen.width(3)

# set up the window

root = Tk()
root.title('turtle shapes')
root.geometry('600x400+100+100')

# make the interface

turtleLabel = Label(root, text='Turtle Fractals Generator')
turtleLabel.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)

# order widgets

orderLabel = Label(root, text='Order')
orderLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)

orderEntry = Entry(root)
orderEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)

# length widgets

lengthLabel = Label(root, text='Length')
lengthLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)

lengthEntry = Entry(root)
lengthEntry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)

# button widgets

def clearF():

    # Clear the entries
    orderEntry.delete(0, 'end')
    lengthEntry.delete(0, 'end')

clearButton = Button(root, text='Clear', command=clearF)
clearButton.grid(row=3, column=1)

# list

def selection():
    selections = nameList.curselection()

    if selections:
        selection = selections[0]

        if selection < len(fractals):
            name, definition = fractals[selection]
            definition()

# create list
listbox = Listbox(root, selectmode=SINGLE) # select mode is type of selection
listButton = Button(root, text='chose fractal')

labelVar = StringVar()
nameLabel = Label(root, textvariable=labelVar)
nameLabel.grid(row=2, column=7, columnspan=2)
labelVar.set('choose a fractal')

nameList = Listbox(root)

for name, definition in fractals:
    nameList.insert(END, name)

nameList.grid(row=4, column=7, columnspan=2)

selectionButton = Button(root, text='Draw', command=selection)
selectionButton.grid(row=5, column=7, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

General comments about your code:

Find and follow a good Python coding style -- it makes understanding your code more difficult when you invent your own coding "style".

This isn't the correct way to integrate turtle with tkinter.  Search StackOverflow, or the turtle documentation, for `RawTurtle` and `TurtleScreen`, the classes you use instead of `Turtle` (aka `Pen`) and `Screen` when embedding in an existing Tk window structure.

Comment: your code worked for me however I kept getting an error with importing the turtlegraphics file so I had to change some things around. Also thanks for the advise. I'll keep that in mind